# replace a string with another if a particular string is not preceding it

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed

How to replace "if" to "abc if" in multiple file using shell scripting. But I don't want to change if when it preceded by else?

For example:

```
if (var3 == 4'h0)
   a =    bvec[0];
else
if (var3 == 4'h1)
a =    bvec[1];
```

should be converted to

```
abc if (var3 == 4'h0)
   a =    bvec[0];
else
if (var3 == 4'h1)
a =    bvec[1];
```

Please note:
1.there are can be indefinite space or a new line between else and if.
2. There are more codes present in the file also
3. I wanted the changes to occur in the same file only.
4. I want to pass a list of filename to the script

I have tried with:

```
sed -r 's/else[[:blank:]]if/temp1/g;s/if/abc if/g;s/temp1/else if/g' file.v
```

Comment: Can there be a newline between?

Comment: Can there longer code, e.g. a `{ ...; ...; ...;}` ?

Comment: Alright so whats your attempt towards your problem ?

Comment: "*I want to do X*" is not a question.

Answer (score 1):

WIth GNU awk for multi-char RS, gensub(), and word boundaries:

```
$ awk -v RS='^$' -v ORS= '{
    gsub(/@/,"@A")
    gsub(/#/,"@B")
    $0 = gensub(/\<else(\s+)if\>/,"#\\1#","g")
    gsub(/\<if\>/,"abc &")
    $0 = gensub(/#(\s+)#/,"else\\1if","g")
    gsub(/@B/,"#")
    gsub(/@A/,"@")
    print
}' file
abc if (var3 == 4'h0)
   a =    bvec[0];
else
if (var3 == 4'h1)
a =    bvec[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to simulate negative variable lookbehind regex in Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = do { local $/; <> };
$str =~ s/((?:else\s*if|if))/my_subst($1)/ge;
print $str;

sub my_subst {
    my $res = $_[0];
    if ( $_[0] !~ /^else/ ) {
        $res = "abc if";
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**Output**:

```
$ p.pl file.txt 
abc if (var3 == 4'h0)
   a =    bvec[0];
else
if (var3 == 4'h1)
a =    bvec[1];
```

**Update**:

To use inplace-edit on a list of files:

```
$^I = '.bak';
$/ = undef;
while (<>) {
    s/((?:else\s*if|if))/my_subst($1)/ge;
    print;
}
```

Then you can just run `p.pl file*.txt` and the backup files will get `.bak` suffix.

Comment: can you please update the code so that the change will be effected in the same file only and I want to pass a list of filenames in which i want these changes.

Comment: @JayeshRanjan You can redirect output to a file in the terminal using `>`

Comment: As i have a list of file name in file which i want to pass. It is not possible to use >

Comment: Can you please explain the things you have use in the script

Comment: See [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html) for `$^I` and `$/` and [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html) and [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) for the regex substitution modifier

Comment: You code is converting all the string which have "if" in them . I want only the if control statement  "if" should be converted to "abc if". you can search for "if (" or "if("

Comment: @JayeshRanjan Just change the regex as you need to.

Comment: @JayeshRanjan Did you manage to solve your problem? Feel free to contact me by email if you have additional questions.